# How to disable junit tests with ConditionalOnProperty?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I conditioned some endpoints in my service with environment variables as a feature flag. For one Controller I put `@ConditionalOnProperty("enable.v2.foo")` at class level and for another
I put `@ConditionalOnProperty("enable.v2.ba.endpoint2")` on the specific method.
Now I have some end to end junit 4 tests that call these endpoints. Signature is

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TaxServiceApp.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class E2ETest432 {
...
```

So I figured I can just put `@ConditionalOnProperty("enable.v2.ba.endpoint2")` on specific tests at method level and on class level if the whole class tests an endpoint I want to switch of.

But if I run all tests, then thos tests are run as well. I even verified that they are read and have the correct value:

```
  @Value("${enable.v2.ba.endpoint2}")
  private boolean switchAsBoolean;


  @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:dataset/....sql")
  @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:dataset/....sql")
  @Test
  @ConditionalOnProperty("enable.v2.ba.endpoint2")
  public void shouldReturnDeliveryCostsForVehicle() throws IOException {
      Assertions.assertThat(switchAsBoolean).isFalse();
      ...
  }
```

This test fails because the endpoint is not there (->status code is unexpectedly 404) not because the value is false!

How can I condition my tests on the same feature flag?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) annotation to the test to set the property value.
for example

@TestPropertySource(properties = "enable.v2.ba.endpoint2 = true")

You'd have to have 2 test classes, one annotated true and the other false.